# how to exit the loop and come to the ContentView swiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-environment

[Onboarding screen, Signup and Password recovery](https://liquidcoder.com/swiftui-login-signup-and-password-recovery-uis/) I'm working on this link project.
How can I go to the ContentView after login?, how do I get out of the loop and come to the ContentView?
I would be happy if you help..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ZStack to overlay the different pieces of content and conditionally choose which are visible.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isLoggedIn = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if self.isLoggedIn {
                Text("You're In!")
            } else {
                LoginView(isLoggedIn: self.$isLoggedIn)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where the LoginView updates the state to indicate a valid login.

```
struct LoginView: View {
    @Binding var isLoggedIn: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Button("Log in") {
            self.isLoggedIn = true
        }
    }
}
```

Because SwiftUI presents views as a function of state, there is no loop running to present the login view and then pass off to the other content. Instead all possible content is described and any time @State is changed, the views are re-created to match the current values.